# What is the lightest way computationally to video record rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to evaluate one of the SLAMs using rviz to output the results on ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is when I tried to do a desktop record using software such as RecordMyDesktop and Green Recorder, the results of the SLAM are affected, apparently the SLAM is so greedy computationally.

Is there a way that is computationally light to store what rviz is outputting?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264583/what-is-the-lightest-way-computationally-to-video-record-rviz/) by [houssem](https://answers.ros.org/users/30651/houssem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag record the topics displayed by rviz, then play them back later and if still needed record the desktop with slam no longer running.

Consider adding another computer dedicated to recording, it will be less cpu to send topics over the network than save them locally to disk.  rviz itself may be taking a lot of cpu (I see it slow down the most under moderately large point clouds) so having this second computer to observe the output even if it isn't getting recorded isn't a bad idea.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1